# Fetching group Ids from OpportunityShare

Tags: apex, schema

I want to fetch all group Ids from an OpportunityShare table for a particular opportunity. I intend to do this by comparing all the Ids in UseOrGroupId column in opportunity share table against key prefix **OOG** and then retrieve those particular Ids, is it the right approach ? Because in documentation for DescribeSObjectResult object I see a  Note *that a key prefix can sometimes be shared by multiple objects so it does not always uniquely identify an object*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for your concern about the key prefix being shared by multiple objects, the User Key Prefix is `'005'` and I believe the UserOrGroupId has to reference either User or Group.

Best practice would probably be to pull the Key Prefix through `getDescribe`. I say this because even though you know the prefix and it is not likely to change, this sort of convention makes your code much easier to read.

```
final String groupKeyPrefix = Group.SObjectType.getDescribe().getKeyPrefix();

Set<String> groupIds = new Set<String>();
for (Id userOrGroupId : userOrGroupIds)
{
    if (String.valueOf(userOrGroupId).startsWith(groupKeyPrefix)
    {
        groupIds.add(userOrGroupId);
    }
}
```